# Provider 'Task' must return a value from $get factory method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written an angularjs factory as below

```
var app = angular.module('Todolist', ['ngResource']);

  app.factory('Task', [
    '$resource', function($resource) {
      $resource('users/:user_id/tasks/:id', {
        id: '@id'
      }, {
        update: {
          method: 'PUT'
        }
      });
    }
  ]);

app.controller('TasksCtrl', [
  '$scope', 'Task', function($scope, Task) {
    $scope.tasks = Task.query({
      status: 'incompleted'
    });

   $scope.completed_tasks = Task.query({
     status: 'completed'
    });

 }
]);
```

But I keep getting the error and have no clue where I've done the mistake.

```
Error: [$injector:undef] Provider 'Task' must return a value from $get factory method.
```

So what's wrong with it?

Comment: You've got to `return` your `$resource` from the factory as well

Comment: @Alexander Shmatko if you do not need new instances of that resource consider using de service recipe. It's basically a singleton. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a factory. They must have a **$get** method defined on them that creates new instances of whatever it should be creating.
Check the documentation for Provider Recipe here : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers